# A way to maintain if and else conditions

Tags: javascript, loops, ejs

hey guys i have a code currently looping some items. For the first "if" condition it gives an output when a condition is met and nothing when there is no statement matching the condition. But when i immediately insert the "else" condition it completely skips the first "if statement" and goes straight to the "else" statement even when the "if" condition is correct. Using ejs

```js
<%Movies.find(element => {%>
  <%if(element.text === Details.title){%>
    <%console.log("found")%>
    <%return true%>
  <%} else {%>
    <%console.log("none")%>
    <%return true%>
  <%}%>
<%})%>
```

what do i do
thanks...

Comment: When returning inside an if statement, the else is not needed. (I don't think that will solve your issue though)

Comment: so how do i get an output when the "if" statement is not met @evolutionxbox

Comment: In the same way, just without the else block. `if(condition) { return true; } return false;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% Movies.find(element => {
  console.log(element.text, Details.title)
  if(element.text === Details.title) {
    console.log("found")
    return true;
  } 
  console.log("none") 
  return true
}) %>
```

**[EDIT]**

You can simply do:

```
<% Movies.find(element => {
  console.log(element.text === Details.title ? "found" : "none")
  return element.text === Details.title
}) %>
```

Comment: @FahdDevi still the same result it's still skipping the first "if" condition

Comment: Did you log "element.text" & "Details.title" ?